# Using HttpPlatformHandler with IIS, is it possible to set a range limit for random ports assigned to %HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%?

Tags: windows, iis, port, asp.net

I have a microservice created with Flask that I have set up to run on Windows Server behind IIS using HttpPlatformHandler. It's working great except for one problem.

There are other applications running on the servers that listen on specific ports. There's a possibility of conflict if an HttpPlatformHandler process starts on one of those ports.

Is there any way to limit the range for the port number that HttpPlatformHandler passes to the %HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT% variable in the web.config when starting a process?

Comment: You will have to disclose more about the "other applications running on the servers". Overall the possibility of conflict is too low to be considered.

Comment: @LexLi Anywhere between 10 and 30 reserved listening ports in the 2000-15000 range depending on the server. I recognize it's statistically unlikely to happen but I'd rather set a range of ports specifically for my process if at all possible. 

The more likely conflict will be during the architecture/security review process.

Comment: If your situation involves a formal architecture/security review process, I wonder why containers are not yet used to separate server roles into isolate ones (so that the possibility of conflict can be almost reduced to zero). I don't think HttpPlatformHandler offers a setting for that, but an alternative option is to switch to ARR as reverse proxy, so that your Python application server can sit on a fixed port.

Answer (score -1):

In the  element in the web.config , you can set the arguments attribute to include the desired port. For example:

```
<httpPlatform processPath="%PYTHON_EXE%" arguments="%MY_APP_HOME%\your_flask_app.py --port=your_desired_port_number" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\python.log">
```

Comment: Then HttpPlatformHandler cannot find the application server and an gateway error is expected.

Comment: That will force the process listen on the desired port, but HttpPlatformHandler will forward to %HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT% whether or not you include it in the arguments.